bazel build python interpreter from source with custom configure options
my codebase has both C binary and C based python extension, and a python script test, it loads c extension, and run C binary. I use precompiled python interpreter from rules_python.
but when I build asan/tsan variants ( so it can check both C binary and python extension don't have memory/thread bugs), python extension won't load because the precompiled interpreter from rules_python is not built with asan/tsan.
I know that I can use dynamic asan and LD_PRELOAD, but I wonder if possible to build python interpreter from source, with my bazel asan/tsan copt applied?  or can I pass different configure options conditionally depends on my copts? (the python configure script already support asan/tsan options)
I found https://github.com/kku1993/bazel-hermetic-python/blob/master/WORKSPACE maybe helpful, but not sure if that's the best way ? how can I detect different copts when running configure ? or there're already some bazel function I can reuse so it auto build python interpreter with my custom copts?
Thanks for advise.
